# Is it possible to create a linked server between the ServiceNow ODBC driver and an AWS/RDS SQL Server instance?

Tags: amazon-rds, odbc, linked-server

I have an internal .NET 7 web application that uses an MSSQL database hosted on Amazon RDS.

I have a requirement to create a linked server to query data from a separate ServiceNow DB instance.

The only way I can see to do this is:

- Install a new instance of MSSQL/SQLExpress on a Windows Server.
- Install the ServiceNow ODBC driver on the same Windows Server and configure a System DSN to point to my service now instance.
- Configure a .NET DataContext in my .NET 7 web app that points to the linked server on MSSQL/SQLExpress.

Q: Is there any way I can bypass the (extraneous!) SQLExpress install, and configure the linked server for the ServiceNow ODBC directly on my AWS RDS instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be "no".

If I need an ODBC connection...then deploying it to an on-prem MSSQL (like SQLExpress) appears to be the only option.

I *CANNOT* install my Service Now ODBC driver to AWS/RDS ... because the AWS/RDS instance is "serverless" ([SASS](https://www.techtarget.com/searchcloudcomputing/definition/Software-as-a-Service))... and consequently there's no "server" to install/configure the ODBC driver on. Besides additional restrictions on MSSQL "linked servers" for AWS/RDS instances...

Relevant links:

- https://repost.aws/questions/QUK6guwZqPTUKeTGZPwtrF3Q/rds-ms-sql-server-odbc-linked-server-connection-issues

> Linked Server is supported for only SQL Server (EC2 or on-premises) to
> RDS SQL Server RDS SQL Server to SQL Server (RDS, EC2, or on-premises)
> vs. RDS linked server to on-prem...

- https://repost.aws/questions/QU0RwSEdafRDasrTsn11b_3g/how-to-install-3rd-party-odbc-driver-at-rds-sql-server
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implement-linked-servers-with-amazon-rds-for-microsoft-sql-server/